# White background show as transparent in TextFIeld

Tags: xcode, uitextfield, ios14

I'm using the new Xcode beta version 12.0 beta 3 (12A8169g).
During the first check, I noticed that TextField with white background shows as transparent background TextField:

TextField on iOS 14:
[image: TextField on iOS 14]

TextField on iOS 13.3:
[image: TextField on iOS 13.3]

I was trying to change the TextField background but nothing is happening.

Comment: Same behaviour on Xcode 12 beta 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are setting color from xib/storyboard. Don't do that. Just set background color from viewDidLoad() like the following.

```
self.myTF.backgroundColor = .white
```

It worked for me.

Comment: On Xcode 12 beta it didn’t work from the code ether. I had to wait for Apple to release Xcode to the public and did a workaround: added a UIView as a background

Comment: I used Xcode 12.1 stable version. Don't rely on beta.

Comment: Do you still experience this issue?

Comment: Yes, experienced, but fixed with the solution mentioned.